# Is there a way for SVG strokes to "skip" intersecting each other, the same sort of way that CSS has `text-decoration-skip-ink`?

Tags: svg, stroke

I could probably manually fake it using a solid-edged drop shadow filter around the strokes, set to the background color, but that's neither resilient nor ideal.

Visually, instead of this:

[image]

I want to have this (if the circle is on top):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A posible solution would be creating a mask with a white rectangle and a black stroked `<use>` element  that is using the circle.

Please note that the white rectangle is covering all the svg element and  the stroke-width of the `<use>` element is wider than the stroke of the circle.

This way you create a hole in the rect that is letting you to see whatever you have in the background.

```html
<svg fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="3">
  <mask id="m">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
    <use xlink:href="#c" stroke-width="10" />
  </mask>

  <rect x="10" y="5" width="70" height="70" mask="url(#m)" />

  <circle id="c" cx="80" cy="75" r="40" />

</svg>
```